# How to combine multiple commands when piped through xargs?

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have the following command:

`!nohup fswatch -o ~/Notes -e "\\.git.*" | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh ~/auto_commit.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

I want to inline what's in the `auto_commit.sh` file:

```
cd ~/Notes
git add -A
git commit --allow-empty-message -am ""
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I replace `sh ~/auto_commit.sh` with `cd ~/Notes && git add -A && git commit --allow-empty-message -am ""` it doesn't work.

I'd like to avoid using an external script file and do it all inline.

Comment: Can you start your nohup in the ~/Notes folder and use `git commit -A ...`, making it all one command ?

Comment: I'd prefer not to since this command is fired off by a vim event, so it's in a vim config that's not located in the `~/Notes` dir. I suppose I can put that config in there and symlink it, but not sure what the system will think the `PWD` is.

Comment: could you run it in a subshell? `{cd ~/Notes; git add -A; git commit --allow-empty-message -am ""}`

Comment: I was wrong, but I helped I guess. `{ ...; }` is not a subshell and you cannot really use a subshell as the target of `xargs` afaik

Comment: @WillBarnwell sorry, I didn't mean that as a snub. I didn't know you were going to delete your answer and just wanted others to be aware of the subtle difference. Really meant no offense and am very grateful for what you pointed out. It set me in the right direction.

Comment: No, no snub/offense taken, my answer was actually totally wrong and thus should be deleted, but im glad it indirectly helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up with was:

```
nohup fswatch -o ~/Notes -e "\\.git.*" | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'cd ~/Notes; git add -A; git commit --allow-empty-message -m ""' > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

Thanks to Will Barnwell and whjm for your help.

Also, this was for a vim script, so the formatting had to be slightly different (in case others are looking for a solution to a similar problem):

```
autocmd BufWinEnter *.note silent! execute '!nohup fswatch -o . -e "\\.git.*" | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c ''git add -A; git commit --allow-empty-message -m ""'' > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

Note that where Will Barnwell was wrong is that the `{..}` is not a subshell, and the `sh -c` command expects a string. So the curly braces were unnecessary, and in my case added an undesired git commit message.

Also, when used in this vim script with the vim `execute` function, the entire command had to be wrapped in quotes. Doubling up on single quotes (not double quotes mind you) allowed the `execute` function to accept the argument as a normal string, and things worked fine.